# What is the best way to replace tensorflows placeholder for version 2.5.0 in google colabs python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am working on a project and am trying to replace this block of code with something that works. I am using version 2.5.0 of tensorflow and am faced with the following error. AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

```
for ui in range(num_unrollings):
    train_inputs.append(tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape [batch_size,D],name='train_inputs_%d'%ui))
    train_outputs.append(tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size,1], name = 'train_outputs_%d'%ui))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype, shape=None, name=None)
```

Official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize you could use other versions for only one task like this!